# How to check how many line start with digit

Tags: python, string, for-loop, split

Assume a string '`text`' represents multiple lines, how do I count that how many lines starts with a digit?

```
def digit_leading_lines(text):
    n = 0
    newlist = text.split()
    for i in range (len(newlist)):
        for j in range (len(newlist[i])):
            if newlist[i][j].isdigit() == True:
                n += 1
    return n
```

Once I test it with text = '`AAA\n1st`', it gives the right output as 1.
But when I input text = "`\t4G\nHz\n`", which cause the first line start with tab, and output should be 0. However, it still gives me 1 as output.

And when I test for "`0\n0  3\n\n`" it gives me wrong output 3. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is:

```
def digit_leading_lines(text):
    lines = text.splitlines()
    count = 0
    for line in lines:
        if line and line[0].isdigit():
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Your code totally works. When I change "if line and line[0].isdigit():" into "if  line[0].isdigit():". the output becomes different. Could you please explain?

Comment: You also should check if line is empty("0\n0 3\n\n".splitlines() will return
['0', '0 3', ''] ) and 'if line' statement will check such situation

Answer (score 2):

#### Why your code doesn't work

That's because you're looping on each character in each line. Your output make sense because it simply counts the number of digits in the file and *not* the lines that *begins* with a digit.

#### Making it work

There are many possible solutions for your problem, the straightforward solution would be iterating on lines, and only check the first character on each line:

```
with open('file') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        # check if the first character is a digit
        # and increment the count
```

<sup>Tip for life: Always debug your code to better understand its flow</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.split()` which takes out all whitespace.  Instead, use `.splitlines()`.  Also, you can do this with a generator expression:

```
def digit_leading_lines(text):
    return sum(1 for line in text.splitlines() if line and line[0].isdigit())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the split method with '\n' parameter so that it splits only based on newline. And then you can simplily your numeric value checking like in the code below.

```
def digit_leading_lines(text):
    n = 0
    newlist = text.split('\n')
    for l in newlist:
        if len(l) and l[0].isdigit():
            n += 1
    return n

print digit_leading_lines("\t4G\nHz\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet using regex:

```
data = """
The volcano is covered by a thick ice cap,
one of the largest in the tropics,
5 that has existed since at least the Pliocene and has
3 undergone several phases of expansion and reduction. As of
2016, the ice cap is in retreat; one estimate predicts that
it will disappear by
2045. The retreat of the Coropuna glaciers threatens the water
supply of tens of thousands of people,
and interaction between volcanic activity and glacial effects has
45 generated mudflows that could be a hazard to surrounding populations
if the mountain returns to volcanic activity.
"""

rx = re.compile(r"^\d", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

count = 0
for match in rx.finditer(data):
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Output: `5`

Where `data` contains your multiline text.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows you to do exactly what you want: sum all lines, where the first letter is a digit. You can use the fact that `False` or empty string have value `1` in a numerical context and sum up:

```
sum(
    (line and line[0]).isdigit() 
    for line in text.splitlines()
)
```

you need `(line and line[0])` to avoid `IndexError` when line is empty, in which case the first falsy value is returned (empty string), which is not a digit so returns `False`.